# No static method metafactory (OptaPlanner)

Tags: java, android-studio, java-8, optaplanner

Recently I added OptaPlanner dependency to my build.gradle in order to use the Vehicle Routing Problem of the Library. When I tried to use the solver I received the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
```

I have google and found that I need to enable JDK 1.8 for the same which I have done in the build.gradle however it still doesn't seem to go away. I am attaching the build.gradle file as well. Any suggestions ? (I am using Android-Studio)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.groceryrouter"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/kie.conf'
        exclude 'META-INF/ErraiApp.properties'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation group: 'com.jtransc', name: 'jtransc-rt', version: '0.6.8'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '20030203.000550'
    implementation('org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:7.36.0.20200331') {
        exclude group: 'xmlpull'
        exclude group: 'org.drools'
        // todo exclude, didn't work on optaplanner 6.1.0
        //exclude group: 'org.kie'
    }
    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Robolectric environment
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.9"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're using getter annotations. Use field annotations instead.

It's an improvement we made to use MethodHandles instead of reflection to call getters, and they are faster, but it has compatibility issues on Android and Graal.

Comment: Yes I am using getter annotations. How do I use field annotations instead ? You are saying it has compatibility issues so how will I be cable to make it work ?

Comment: Instead of putting `@PlanningVariable` etc on a getter `getFoo()`, set it on the field `foo` directly.

Answer (score 0):

In the app's `build.gradle` add this code

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```